# Some items are blocked when taking a screen recording or picture for swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

What I'm trying to do is I want to hide any ui element when the user receives a screen recording or photo, I sent an email to the screenShield kit site, but didn't get any feedback. I have to try another method. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can detect whether the screen is being recorded or not by using;

```
UIScreen.main.isCaptured
```

You can also use notification to track any changes;

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didChangeCaptured(_:)), name: UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification, object: nil)


@objc func didChangeCaptured(_ notification: Notification) {
  if UIScreen.main.isCaptured {
   // do something here
  } else { 
   // do something here 
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a chance to write in swift language? I would be glad if you write

Comment: this is in swift language. you should add the first line to, for instance, inside override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() ... // here  } the rest of the code should be added to the ViewController.

Comment: thank you @Rob I learned a lot from your explanation.